# Lebesgue covering problem's demand for convexivity

Tags: geometry, convex-geometry, discrete-geometry

Is there a specific reason why in the Lebesgue (universal) covering problem only convex sets are admitted as universal coverings?  I see that for any set $X\subseteq{\bf R}^2$ of diameter $\le\alpha$, the convex hull of $X$ also has diameter $\le\alpha$ but can we also deduce that a solution to the covering problem *has* to be convex even if we don't demand it in the question?

Comment: See [this question on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/31315/is-lebesgues-universal-covering-problem-still-open), which constitutes somewhat of a survey on the topic. In the answers of John Baez ([link to answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/151080)) and Philip Gibbs ([link to answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/155608)), who are experts on this problem, the convex and non-convex problems are treated separately, so it seems that the two questions are not known to be equivalent. In other words, as far as I can tell, what you are asking is an open problem.